# Htaccess Redirect always appends source url file name

Tags: .htaccess

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, I'm trying to redirect from http://www.myoldsite.com/subfolder/page.php to http://www.mynewsite.com/new-subfolder1/new-subfolder2/ but the .php file always gets appended to the destination url http://www.mynewsite.com/new-subfolder1/new-subfolder2/page.php, the destination site is a wordpress site, I've tried various different example for htaccess redirects, below is the one I'm using now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/http://www.myoldsite.com/subfolder/page.php?$ $1http://www.mynewsite.com/new-subfolder1/new-subfolder2/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Above rule is not correct and definitely not working. Question is then how you are getting redirected to new URLs?

Comment: I've no idea, I also tried this RewriteRule ^/?subfolder/page.php http://www.mynewsite.com/new-subfolder1/new-subfolder2/? [R=301,L]

Comment: Check presence of other .htaccess, Apache config OR WP plugins etc

Comment: Yes you were correct, I have a plugin called "Quick Redirects", perhaps this is causing the issue